# How to get Past 9 Sundays Date in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am creating Dropdown Which show 10 Sunday first is upcoming sunday and others are past 9 sundays.If today is 9/13/18 so the dropdown would have 9/16/18, 9/9/18, 9/2/18, etc.How did i get these from jquery?

Comment: What did you try? Do you have some parcially working piece of code that we can help you continue working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think jQuery provides such date handling tools. But there is one library I really like when it comes to dates: [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).
Using it you can simply generate the sequence:

```
Array.from({length: 10}, (x,i) => -i*7).map(x => moment().day(x).format('YY/M/D'));
```

[image]

Or even `option` elements:

```
Array.from({length: 10}, (x,i) => -i*7).map(x => $('<option>').text(moment().day(x).format('YY/M/D')));
```

Comment: Thanks.It Help a lot.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, you don't need jquery for this. I simply created a select and populated it with the previous 10 sundays (including this one) by defining prevSunday which is the intial previous sunday, and looping through 10 times setting the date to a new date -7 days from the initial previous Sunday. Hope this is what you were looking for.

html

```
<div id="banner-message">
   <select id="selectPrevSundays"></select>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var prevSunday = new Date();
prevSunday.setDate(prevSunday.getDate() - prevSunday.getDay());


populateSundayDropdown();

function populateSundayDropdown(){
    var select = document.getElementById("selectPrevSundays"); 
    var lengthOfDropdownlist= 10; 

    for(var i = 0; i < lengthOfDropdownlist; i++) {
    var opt = new Date()
    opt.setDate(prevSunday.getDate() - (7*i));

    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```